# JavaScript es 6 convert Map to json object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a Map with key and value as a json object, e.g

```
var myMap = new Map();

myMap.set('1', "mike");
myMap.set('2', "tom");
```

How could I turn it into an object array by re-construct the object schema (due to api requested) with `value` and `fullame` maps to the key and value in above Map like

```
[{value : 1, fullName: "mike"},{value : 2, fullName: "tom"},...]
```

I've tried using

```
Array.from(myMap).map(arr => ({ value: arr[0], fullName: arr[1] }));
```

(Note, the `Array.from(myMap)` will give you the result as array of array like, there is no way to normally destructure using property name

```
[[1, "tom", 28],[2, "mike", 30],...]
```

As it will convert into a nested object array first that I have to find the id and name through index by map like `arr[0]` gives me `value` and `arr[1]` gives me `fullName`...

Is there any other better way around that? Using Lodash is also welcome for suggestions here!

Comment: That's not a JSON object, it is just an object.

Comment: It is not clear at all what your Map object contains.  Neither your Map declaration or your desired object array are valid syntax.  We could probably help you in a matter of minutes if the question was clear about what data you're starting with and what data you want as a result.

Comment: Is the `id` property of the value object always the same as the key in the map?

Comment: Yes assuming it is.

Comment: Then why do you want to change the property name `id` to `value`? That's a bit unclear.

Comment: That's the api request object schema, I don't have control to rename the property name same as `id`

Comment: I've updated the requirement to make it not confusing about the property name of transformed object, now `id` needs become `value` and `name` needs become `fullName`

Comment: @jfriend00 updated the quote.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry my bad, I copied the wrong Map object example, updated the request Map object now

Comment: @KevDing - Well that renders your entire question into a different and massively simpler question.    This part of your question `[[1, "tom", 28],[2, "mike", 30],...]` is still WRONG.  I don't even know why you're asking this.  Iterate the `Map` object and build each object yourself.  It's trivial.  It takes a single `for` loop.

Comment: And, what's wrong with `Array.from(myMap).map(arr => ({ value: arr[0], fullName: arr[1] }));` that you already show.  Should work just fine.  There are no property names in your `Map` object to refer to so not sure what else you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other better way around that?

You could use the second parameter of `Array.from` instead of `map`, and you could use parameter destructuring for the tuple argument:

```
Array.from(myMap, ([value, fullName]) => ({ value, fullName }));
```

But no, there is no way around manually constructing that array of objects with the custom property names `value` and `fullName`.

Comment: This works awesome! That's the answer I've been looking for except my original one while having to use hard-code indexing

Comment: @KevDing There's nothing wrong with hard-coding the indices into the array for which you know that it always has exactly two elements btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the id keys and only get the [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), use

```
Array.from(myMap.values())
```

The [default iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator) yields tuples with both.

Comment: @jfriend00 I found many inconsistencies in the question, so I thought this was what they're looking for. An executable example with a complete (and syntactically valid) desired result would help.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried `Array.from(myMap).map(arr => ({ value: arr[0], name: arr[1] }));` but that will convert into a nested object

It seems you're only missing the `.name` property access on the value part of the entry tuple, to get only the name string and not the entire object:

```
Array.from(myMap).map(arr => ({ value: arr[0], name: arr[1].name }));
//                                                         ^^^^^
```

You can simplify that by using parameter destructuring syntax to

```
Array.from(myMap).map(([value, {name}]) => ({ value, name }));
```

Comment: The result of Array.from(myMap) will give you an array of array like `[[1, "tom", 28],[2, "mike", 30],...]`, you don't have the way to destructuring by syntax. That's why I provided my current solution, but had to take out the name and value by indexing

Comment: @Bergi, Sorry my bad, I copied the wrong Map object example, updated the request Map object now

Comment: @KevDing As jfriend mentioned, please take more care when compiling your questions. I've added yet another post that hopefully is the answer to what you wanted to ask.